# Changed Folder Redirection on Server 2008 R2, I didn't see anything change

Tags: windows-server-2008, directory, folder-redirection

I need some help guys. I've just modified the Folder Redirection Policy on my server at work so the hiarcy resembles windows 7's user folder structure rather than XP. I did this to the book so I know its right. However, I'm still seeing that all the user accounts are still layed out as XP compatible folder hiracys. Is there somthing I need to do to update these accounts with the new policy?

Answer (score 1):

have you checked the app log on your clients?  it will show folder redirection errors.  Also, as reccomended, do a gpupdate /force.  Oh... and if you haven't enabled "wait for network at login" folder redirection sometimes takes two log offs to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Did you force group policy update?

Start > Run:

gpupdate /force